# Error on SugarCRM REST api v4

Tags: sugarcrm

We got error on REST api v4. It blocks us to get data from sugar database. We are using SugarCRM Version 7.6.2.1 (Build 9)

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of SugarWebServiceImplv3_1::get_entry_list() should be compatible with SugarWebServiceImpl::get_entry_list($session, $module_name, $query, $order_by, $offset, $select_fields, $link_name_to_fields_array, $max_results, $deleted = 0) in /home/testsugarcrm/app/www/service/v3_1/SugarWebServiceImplv3_1.php on line 20

Strict Standards: Declaration of SugarWebServiceUtilv4::get_data_list() should be compatible with SugarWebServiceUtilv3_1::get_data_list($seed, $order_by = '', $where = '', $row_offset = 0, $limit = -1, $max = -1, $show_deleted = 0, $favorites = false, $singleSelect = false) in /home/testsugarcrm/app/www/service/v4/SugarWebServiceUtilv4.php on line 638

Strict Standards: Declaration of SugarWebServiceImplv4::get_entries() should be compatible with SugarWebServiceImplv3_1::get_entries($session, $module_name, $ids, $select_fields, $link_name_to_fields_array, $track_view = false) in /home/testsugarcrm/app/www/service/v4/SugarWebServiceImplv4.php on line 21
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

These are *Strict Standards* which will need to be disabled at server/PHP end.

Find your php.ini file (root folder) and change the attribute that is called error_reporting:

from:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL  | E_STRICT
```

to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL &amp; ~E_NOTICE &amp; ~E_WARNING &amp; ~E_STRICT &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will this change only hide the error message? As we also got the issue when using this api. That function get_entry_list doesn't return data although It was ok.